# Accessing sensitive user credentials in entrypoint.sh of docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

Trying to create a few `Airflow` connections and executing the command in `entrypoint.sh` file which is passed as entrypoint file in the `dockerfile`.
As these database credentials are very sensitive, is it possible that we store them securely in `kubernetes` or any other place on `GCP` and based on the `local`, `staging` or `production` we' populate them in the `entrypoint.sh`?

Answer (score 2):

You can store them as kubernetes secret and mount them as an environment variable that will be accessible by entrypoint.sh

Remember kubernetes secret just encode secret as base64 otherwise you can use [sealed secrets](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: redis
    env:
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: username
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: password
  restartPolicy: Never
```